# While loop removes iteration when variable is repeated

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax

I'm following along with the MIT intro to python course to productively fill my time during this quarantine, and I've found something that confuses me a bit.

I'll only post a snippet of the code as I'm just focused on this while loop. If I run the loop below, I'm given the right answer of 159 months:

```
while current_savings < down_payment:
    current_savings += monthly_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12
    months += 1
```

But if I run this next one, it'll give me an answer of 158 months:

```
while current_savings < down_payment:
    current_savings += monthly_savings
    current_savings += (current_savings*0.04)/12
    months += 1
```

I'm just a little confused on why the second string of code will leave a month off. Could anyone explain maybe how this code is being read?

Comment: The issue is in the second one current savings is updated by monthly_savings before being multiplied by 0.04.  So basically you have `current_savings += ((current_savings+monthly_savings)*0.04)/12`

Comment: Order of operations. In the first loop `(current_savings*.04)/12` is executed before adding  `monthly_savings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First one**:

In this one `current_savings` in `(current_savings*0.04)/12` has the first value of `current_savings`.

```
while current_savings < down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings + monthly_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12
    months += 1
```

**Second one:**

```
while current_savings < down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings + monthly_savings
    current_savings = current_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12 //here current_savings in (current_savings*0.04)/12 has changed after the line above
    months += 1
```

I got rid of the `+=` so that the become more logically understandable.